# Помогите решить проблему. Мне нужно чтобы телеграмм бот (telebot, python) хранил заказ каждого пользователя индивидуально

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

На данный момент происходит бардак: условно, если 2 человека используют бота, то у 1го пользователя видно, что заказал 2й пользователь и наоборот.
Пользователь добавляет морс в корзину. Далее название отображается во вкладке [buy]
Пример кода:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'mors_k_05')
def drink_callback(call):
    markup_3_1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Добавить 1 шт '+'✅', callback_data='mors_k_05_1sht')
    markup_3_1.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Укажите количество ' +'➡', callback_data='mors_k_05_kolvo')
    markup_3_1.row(btn2)
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('⬅' + ' Назад', callback_data='drink')
    markup_3_1.row(btn3)
    photo_url = 'https://static.tildacdn.com/stor3238-3233-4030-b961-393331613832/96753182.jpg'
    bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                           media=types.InputMediaPhoto(photo_url), reply_markup=markup_3_1)
    bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                             caption='<u><b>Натуральный клюквенный морс 0,5 л - 98₽:</b></u>\n- 500 г.'
                                     '\n- <u>Клюква, сахар, вода</u>\nЭнергетическая ценность на 100 г:'
                                     '\n- Белки - 0.1г\n- Углеводы - 8.5г'
                                     '\n- Энерг. ценность - 34.4 Ккал', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup_3_1)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'mors_k_05_1sht')
def drink_callback(call):
    order.append('Клюквенный морс 0,5 л - 98₽')
    markup_3_2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Продолжить заказ ' + '➡', callback_data='menu')
    markup_3_2.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Ваш заказ'+ '' , callback_data='buy')
    markup_3_2.row(btn2)
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('⬅' + ' Назад', callback_data='mors_k_05')
    markup_3_2.row(btn3)
    photo_url = 'https://static.tildacdn.com/stor3238-3233-4030-b961-393331613832/96753182.jpg'
    bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                           media=types.InputMediaPhoto(photo_url), reply_markup=markup_3_2)
    bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                             caption='<u>Натуральный клюквенный морс 0,5 л</u>'
                                     '\n<b>ДОБАВЛЕНО В ЗАКАЗ</b>',parse_mode='html',reply_markup=markup_3_2) 
  

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'buy')
def buy_callback(call):
    markup_13 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Перейти к оплате ', callback_data='pizza')
    markup_13.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('⬅' + ' Назад', callback_data='menu')
    markup_13.row(btn2)
    photo_url = 'https://img2.rudalle.ru/images/85/9d/5b/859d5bf2825c41eaa0a3ad635c38342e_00000.jpg'
    bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                           media=types.InputMediaPhoto(photo_url), reply_markup=markup_13)
    bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                             caption='<u><b>ВАШ ЗАКАЗ:</b></u>\n'+'\n'.join(order),parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup_13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве варианта могу предложить хранение заказов в глобальном словаре, с ключами - ID пользователя.
Объявляем:

```
users = {}
```

Добавляем товар:

```
user_id = call.from_user.id

if user_id not in users:
   users[user_id] = []
   
users[user_id].append('Товар')
```

Читаем корзину:

```
user_orders = users[call.from_user.id]

bot.send_message(user_orders)
```

Но лучше для подобных вещей использовать БД, т. к. текущий код будет сильно нагружать память.

Comment: Так же рекомендую не использовать бардак из передаваемых `callback` параметров, а создать API взаимодействия, к примеру первый символ - код действия, далее шесть символов - ID товара с которым совершаем действие, а ID клиента можно вытащить из `call`-параметра.